# Mobile-First Media Queries not overriding original CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, less, media-queries

Let's say I have this:

```
.about_text {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

And:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    .about_text {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 1.500rem;
    }
}
```

If I don't use !important it doesn't override the original CSS... Why can that be? I'm using LESS on a Wordpress site, but I've done it countless of times and this never happened before. I'm taking care of the media queries being after the original CSS.

Comment: Can you provide an example where it isn't actually working?

Answer (score 0):

try using Cascading for the media query as follows if you want the media query to use the css styles -

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    div .about_text {
       font-weight: 600;
       font-size: 1.500rem;
       }
     }
```

Comment: And you are using min-width so it can only take effect whenever the screen is 64em(1024px) or more. And when I checked, it is applying your media query styles for 1024px and more.

Comment: This isn't going to change anything. All you're doing is creating more specificity.

Comment: Also use pixels for media queries as you can never be sure of em's with regards to the pixel value it takes.

Comment: `em` is fine and more flexible than using `px`. Combining `em` with relative font-sizes, your layout will actually work much better when someone changes their font-size/zoom. Using pixels will have no effect on this actually working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code by itself looks good. There may be other conflicting issues, but if not, then you're most likely having an issue with the triggering point of your media query.

Use a px based form of measurement instead of em's for your media queries. Em's are relative whereas px are absolute and yield more consistent results.

```html
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .about_text {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.500rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `em` is fine and is actually a better way to use media queries. Changing it to `px` isn't going to change how it works.

Comment: So long as the base font isn't set to something awkward, accounting for that, then yes, em's work just as well. 

If that's not the issue, then there is most likely another issue at play preventing the media query from taking precedent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.about_text {
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 1.500rem;}

@media screen and (max-width: 64em) {
.about_text {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.125rem;      
}
```

}

Your media query is not applying for mobile devices,it is only apply for desktop or larger size.